# Ruby on Rails - Calculate Rank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

On Rails 4. I am building a contest application. I have three tables relevant to this use case:

**Submissions** - Attributes include:

- `:contest_year` - The year the submission was created
- `:category_id` - The contest category the submission is assigned to
- `:division_id` - The contest division the submission is assigned to (out of five)

**Scores** - Attributes include:

- `:user_id` - The ID of the judge who gives the score
- `:submission_id` - The submission ID the score is tied to
- `:total_score` - The integer number the judge provides as a score of the entry; usually out of ten

**Judges** - Attributes include:

- `:user_id` - The user ID of the judge
- `:category_id` - The category the judge is assigned to score
- `:division_id` - The division the judge is assigned to score

**One submission can have many scores** (as there are multiple judges assigned to its category/division).

The first thing the app must do is find the submission's combined, final score out of all its child scores the various judges give it. I do this using a calculation in submission.rb:

```
  def calculate_final_score
    self.scores.average(:total_score)
  end
```

So basically, it finds all the child scores of the submission and takes the average of those to find the final score. This final score is **NOT an updated attribute** of the submission table, it is a method calculation result.

**Now, here is where my question is.** I need to find a way to calculate the submission's ranking compared to other submissions with the SAME `:contest_year`, `:category_id`, and `:division_id` by comparing that above final score calculation. The ranking system MUST give the same rank when submissions have the same final score (a tie).

tl;dr, I need ranking behavior like this (sample submissions table):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Contest Year | Division ID | Category ID | Final Score | Rank |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |         2013 |           1 |           1 |          10 |    1 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2 |         2013 |           1 |           1 |          10 |    1 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3 |         2013 |           1 |           1 |           8 |    2 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  4 |         2013 |           1 |           1 |           6 |    3 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  4 |         2013 |           1 |           1 |           5 |    4 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  5 |         2013 |           2 |           1 |           8 |    1 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  6 |         2014 |           1 |           2 |           9 |    1 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  7 |         2014 |           1 |           2 |           7 |    2 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This ranking information will be placed in my Active Admin submissions' index table page (and also as part of the CSV table output).

Comment: if the number of scores is below a certain threshold, say 100 entries, i would calculate it in ruby.

Comment: Interesting, would you be able to elaborate further in an answer or link to a similar example? I only know basic ruby calculations.

Answer (score 3):

I am not much familiarly with Rails (or with Ruby). But in our Django application we had a similar situation where we needed to calculate ranks on some computed data. As we were using PostgreSQL as the DB backend, we used Postges's window functions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for rank calculation. Following is a sample PostgresSQL query which can produce the result required by your question.

```
sql_query = %Q{SELECT 
   *, dense_rank() OVER (
       PARTITION BY contest_year, category_id, division_id
       ORDER BY final_score DESC
   )
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Submissions.id, 
        Submission.contest_year AS contest_year, 
        Submission.category_id AS category_id, 
        Submission.division_id AS division_id, 
        AVG(Scores.total_score) AS final_score
    FROM Submissions 
        INNER JOIN Scores ON (Submissions.id = Scores.submission_id)
    GROUP BY 
        Submissions.id, 
        Submission.contest_year, 
        Submission.category_id, 
        Submission.division_id
) AS FinalScores}

submissions_by_rank = Submission.find_by_sql(sql_query)
```

Note: You will need to add `ORDER BY` clause in the query if you want to order the result in a particular fashion.

Comment: I am using SQLite3 for development, will be using PostgreSQL for production eventually. I am having trouble understanding how to place/format this statement into a RoR model method. Nothing I try is working (at least for development). Maybe someone more familiar with Ruby can jump in here, how do I format this statement so that it can be placed in my submissions model? And, if I am not using PostgreSQL for development, will this statement ever work in development?

Comment: SQLite doesn't have window functions as stated here http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/sql-window-functions :(. 

We use postgres for prod and dev both envs in our apps!

Comment: I was afraid of that! Hmm, so I guess there is really no way to test this for development (don't want to switch from SQLite now). I want to award the bounty, but...I have no way of knowing if this works right now! If someone could at least jump in to tell me how to format this for a method in the model (versus a raw query like it is now), I would appreciate that! Maybe later I will make a quick test app with Postgresql as the database to see if this works.

Comment: Hey @Rachel9494, you can use find_by_sql method of rails to make this Query.. e.g
submissions = Submission.find_by_sql(<query>) ....

For reference, see here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, assuming you have that `#calculate_final_score` method set up already:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.rank_all_submissions_by_group
    keys = [ :contest_year, :category_id, :division_id ]
    submission_groups = Submission.all.group_by do |sub|
      values = keys.map { |k| sub.send(key) }
      Hash[key.zip(values)]
    end

    return ranked_submissions_by_group = submission_groups.map do |group, submissions|
      group[:ranked_submissions] = submissions.map do |s|
        [s, s.calculate_final_score]
      end.sort_by(&:last)
    end
  end
end
```

The data that'll be returned will look like:

```
[
  {
    :contest_year => 2013,
    :division_id => 1,
    :category_id => 1,
    :ranked_submissions => [
      [ <Submission>, 10 ],
      [ <Submission>, 10 ],
      [ <Submission>, 8  ],
      [ <Submission>, 6  ],
      [ <Submission>, 5  ],
    ],
  },
  {
    :contest_year => 2013,
    :division_id => 2,
    :category_id => 1,
    :ranked_submissions => [
      [ <Submission>, 8 ],
    ],
  },
  {
    :contest_year => 2014,
    :division_id => 1,
    :category_id => 2,
    :ranked_submissions => [
      [ <Submission>, 9 ],
      [ <Submission>, 7 ],
    ],
  },
]
```

It won't be very performant though, since it just goes through all submissions for all time, makes a lot of copies (I think?), and I'm not using the right sorting algorithm.

If you have any issues/concerns, let me know, and I can update my answer.

**Additional Help**

If you're looking for a way to run a raw query in Ruby, consider this trivial example a suggestion:

```
full_submissions_table_as_hash = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(<<-mysql)
  SELECT *
  FROM #{Submissions.table_name}
mysql
```

Another trivial example showing how the data can be rendered from a controller:

```
# assuming routes are properly set up to actions in HomeController
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def ranked_submissions_text
    render :text => Submission.rank_all_submissions_by_group
  end
  def ranked_submissions_json
    render :json => Submission.rank_all_submissions_by_group
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh my gosh!! This looks so helpful! Some questions, one is kinda stupid: how do I insert this into my Active Admin submissions index table? I put in: column "Rank" do |submission| submission.rank_all_submissions_by_group end -- I knew it wouldn't work but I don't yet have a good understanding of those types of methods. Second: Yes, I too am worried about performance over time. I am not sure what can be done, maybe only return a ranking if :contest_year == Time.now.year? Lastly: Any chance you could insert brief comments explaining the code? Would be SO helpful for me and others learning!

Comment: If you need help understanding what particular Ruby method calls do, you should check out the appropriate documentation. All the methods I'm using, `group_by`, `map`, `zip`, `sort_by`, etc are all in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html, in a very readable format and with examples.

Comment: As for inserting values into an ActiveRecord table, I've the same advice regarding documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html.

Comment: By the way, it'd be nice if you could upvote and/or accept this answer if it solves your problem. I've updated my answer with a trivial example showing how to display the results on a page.

Comment: I will definitely accept this answer as soon as I can verify that it works. I have updated my question at the bottom to include the new error message, I am sure I'm doing something wrong but not sure what!

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with ActiveAdmin, so I can't say what exactly needs to be done to render data in ActiveAdmin. Notice also that the `render` call was intended for use in the controller, not the model. Lastly, the error you're getting is because you just copied my example verbatim into your code, and the example variable names I used don't match what you have in your system.

Comment: Oh, whelp, I feel pretty silly now! I will take a harder look tonight (grace period expires tomorrow afternoon). Thanks again for your assistance.